# Where is an error?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I want div 1 and div 2 to fit in bigbox [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pmRsQ/2/)

help me to find an error

Comment: You can't completely change a question you asked nearly two months ago and had an answer for, to a totally new question. You need to begin a separate, new question.

Comment: I'd like to....but i can't. It is forbidden to ask questions from my account, and i don't know why.

Comment: Then you need to contact team@stackoverflow.com or post a question about it on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Please don't change the context of your questions. You have been blocked from asking questions due to a pattern of extremely low quality questions. What you can do is improve them to the point that they earn up votes, and answer other questions helpfully (also earning votes). Votes are the only thing that will allow you to ask questions again.

Answer (score 12):

On your #box div, add the rule `overflow:auto;`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pmRsQ/1/)**.

Comment: this is just a fix(patch) or it is good way to do?

Comment: No, this is a normal way to handle containing floated divs.

Comment: that's a way, [http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) this is another and the other answer is right also.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line after closing the second div

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

so the whole code will be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ДОСИТЬ ЦЕ ТЕРПІТИ!!!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        <div id="title">bigbox</div>
        <div id="one">
            <div class="who">div 1</div>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            <div class="who">div 2</div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: i dont think this is right answer